# sort mapReduce result in mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to sort the result produced by mapReduce function. 
I can see that there is option to sort mapReduce input using

```
db.runCommand(
           {
             mapReduce: <collection>,
             map: <function>,
             reduce: <function>,
             out: <output>,
             query: <document>,
             sort: <document>,

           }
         )
```

Although I provide the sort field using above command, my result is not sorted. with or without sort option it produces the same result. I can sort these by creating new collection with **out:"collection"** and sort it, but I don't want to create intermediate collection, I want my output to be **inline ( out: { inline:1} )**.

I have a collection named **post**. 
Eg:

```
{
   postID:1,
   userID:10000001,
   title:"1st Post",
   text:"I this is first post in this collection",
   img: "100002.jpg",
   time: 1397736624(timestamp),
   likes:[1000002,1000006] (userID's),
   shares:[1000003,1000005] (userID's)
}
```

Now I want to retrieve all posts also have to calculate the number of likes and shares for each post. I can't retrieve all the likes and shares of each post because its waste of space. so I choose mapReduce to calculate the number of likes and shares. My mapReduce operation is:

below code is in php:

```
$map=function(){ emit(this.date,{postID:this.postID,userID:this.userID,title:this.title,postimg:this.postimg,text:this.text,date:this.date,like:this.like,share:this.share,like_count:this.like.length,share_count:this.share.length})}

$reduce=function(){ }

$result=$this->db->command(array(
            'mapreduce'=>"post"
            'map'=>$map,
            'reduce'=>$reduce,
            'out'=>array('inline'=>1),
                    'sort'=>array('date'=>-1)  

        ));
```

The result is not sorted. I know that the sort option is to sort documents before mapReduce. How to sort results?

somebody help to get the sorted result.

Comment: It can be done, though not obvious. It's a bit of a cheat that involves putting something in the emitted key to represent the sort order you want. You can try and work that out or post some actual data and code here so you can get some pointers.

Comment: I know that can be done, but how?. Can you explain how this mapReduce works?.

Comment: Easier to show you with the code. There is no actual option to "sort" the output. The output is always ordered by the "key" value. But that is the trick, forcing the key as a compound key that includes a leading element in the sort order you want. But still be valid for passing to reduce. I would encourage you to post something, as this question is very abstract and possibly mapReduce is not even the correct operation for your particular problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn Now I have edited my questions please check it

Comment: Sure. So I notice you not actually reducing and by what you are doing there is a better way than mapReduce. But what is the sort order you want? Likes? Shares? Post_id?

Comment: @NeilLunn I want to sort by time(DESC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your query can be done using [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) which is a much better option than mapReduce as it uses native code rather than a JavaScript interpreter and therefore is muxh faster.

Super easy in release 2.6 and onwards:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "postID":1,
        "userID": 1,
        "title": "1,
        "text": 1,
        "img": 1,
        "time": 1,
        "likes": { "$size": "$likes" },
        "shares": { "$size": "$shares" },
    }},
    { "$sort": { "time": -1 } }
])
```

A little more involved in prior 2.4 versions, still faster than mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "_id": {
            "postID": "$postID",
            "userID": "$userId",
            "title": "$title",
            "text": "$text",
            "img": "$img",
            "time": "$time",
            "likes": "$likes",
            "shares": "$shares"
        },
        "likes": 1
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$likes" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "likes": { "$sum": 1 }
        "shares": { "$first": "$_id.shares" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$shares" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "likes": { "$first": "$likes" },
        "shares": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "postID": "$_id.postID",
        "userID": "$_id.userId",
        "title": "$_id.title",
        "text": "$_id.text",
        "img": "$_id.img",
        "time": "$_id.time",
        "likes": "$likes",
        "shares": "$shares"
    }},
    { "$sort": { "time": -1 } }
])
```

And also for mapReduce, you'll hate how simple this is:

```js
var mapper = function() { 

    emit(
        {   
            counter: counter,
            time: this.time
        },
        {
            postID: this.postID,
            userID:this.userID,
            title:this.title,
            postimg:this.postimg,
            text:this.text,
            time:this.time,
            like:this.like,
            share:this.share,
            like_count:this.like.length,
            share_count:this.share.length
        }
    );
    counter++;
};
```

And then to invoke:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    function(){},
    {
        "out":   { "inline": 1 },
        "sort":  { "time": -1 },
        "scope": { "counter": 0 }
    }
)
```

So by making the "input" sort order the order that you want and then by assigning an "ascending" order of "counter" from a "scope global" in the mapper function as the leading part of the key, the "descending" order is preserved.

But use the aggregation approach, it's way better for what you want to do.

Comment: In **2nd aggregation** method suppose if the like field is empty then while $unwind the document is not included, as a result the field of likes and shares are missing from result.

Comment: @vinothkumar Yes that is a problem with the aggregation pipline, in that an empty array will negate all the document content. You can either exclude them with a $match condition, which is pretty hard with your structure or fall back to the mapReduce method. But in 2.6 and on-wards the problem is resolved by the $size operator.